# Python Reset Auto Increment on MariaDB table not working

Tags: python, mariadb

So I have a python file that has a connection to a MariaDB server. The connection works, so that is not the problem. Select, Deletes and so on work, but when I tried the Alter statement to reset the auto-increment, the "cursor.execute" statement would freeze my program. This is my code:

```
def ResetAutoIncrement_MariaDB(table):
    connect_MariaDB()
    try:
        statement = ("ALTER TABLE %s AUTO_INCREMENT = 1" % (table))
        cursor.execute(statement)
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

So when I execute the following function for example, my code would freeze when it reached the "cursor.execute(statement)" in the "ResetAutoIncrement_MariaDB(table)" function above.

```
def deleteWholeTable_MariaDB(table):
    connect_MariaDB()
    try:
        statement = ("DELETE FROM %s" % (table))
        cursor.execute(statement)
        ResetAutoIncrement_MariaDB(table)
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

The DELETE in this function works, but the other function doesn't. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
def connect_MariaDB():
    try:
        global conn
        conn = mariadb.connect(
            user="user",
            password=USERPASSWORD,
            host="192.168.76.3",
            port=3306,
            database="Discord_Bots"
        )
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Get Cursor
    global cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: What is `connect_MariaDB`? How are `cursor` and `conn` defined? If `ResetAutoIncrement_MariaDB` is running in a different connection, it will be waiting on the metadata lock because `DELETE FROM..` isn't committed. Recommend `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead of `DELETE {all}`. Also `ALTER TABLE` and `TRUNCATE` aren't transactional.

Comment: I edited my main post, connect_mariaDB is now added.